# Upload a document in remote Filesystem and then persist document metadata in database in same transaction?

Tags: spring, rest, jpa, transactions, upload

We are developing a REST interface. The consumer will send a pdf file as base64 encoded string as a field in JSON post request. Other fields in the JSON contain metadata about the file. We are consuming another **REST** service to upload the document. Once the document is uploaded, the document reference returned from the service has to be stored in db along with other metadata. We wondering if there's a transnational way of doing so in one single request or do we have to expose 2 end points, one for the upload and the second to store data in db?

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, there should be only one endpoint exposed for client. In your service class, you can make API call to file upload service and get document reference and store everything (reference no and metadata) in DB. You can annotate both methods with @Transactional to make them as single transaction. So, in case the file upload service returns an error or your service throws an error, the entire transaction will be rolled back and error will be propagated back to user.

Comment: Upload service is a rest service. You cannot bind it with spring @Transactional. So a rollback in db won't rollback/delete the file from filesystem.

Comment: Got it. I was in assumption that the file upload service is a 3rd party system which is not in your control. I don't think there is a way around. You need to have another end point hosted by file service to delete the file in case of exception occurs in your code.